# PHP values not posting when 2 forms are posted in quick succession

Tags: php, apache, post

I'm using Apache 2.2.22, PHP 5.3.10 and IE7 (it's on work intranet so I have no control over the version of IE). I was using a later version of Apache (2.4.3, on which my php was working perfectly) but I need to authenticate users and apparently 2.4.3 isn't compatible with mod_auth_sspi.so.

Anyway, I have 3 php pages (index.php --> stage2.php --> stage3.php). When I submit a form on index.php and post to stage2.php, the values are received corrently. However, if I then submit stage2.php and try to post values to stage3.php immediately (after 5 secs), the $_POST values are empty. If I wait 10 seconds, it works properly.

It also works fine if I use GET instead of POST but stage2.php is a search results page and potentially has to pass a large number of variables to stage3.php. I don't know if there's a limit on URL length but it could be thousands of characters long depending on how many results are found.

Also, I've tried setting the header to expire in the past, with no luck.

```
if(!strpos(strtolower($_SERVER[HTTP_USER_AGENT]), "msie") === FALSE) {
   header("HTTP/1.x 205 OK");
} else {
   header("HTTP/1.x 200 OK");
}    
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, cachehack=".time());
header("Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=-1, pre-check=-1", false);
```

Am I missing something? Is there a setting somewhere which sets the time between posting forms?

Dion

Update @ aleation

The actual pages are huge but I can recreate the problem using a simple html form (test_form.html and test_form.php).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>

<form name="RequestForm" method="post" action="test_form.php">
<input name="firstname" type="text" id="firstname">
<input name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname">

<input type="submit" class="nextbutton" id="next_button" name="save" value="Send">
</form>

</body>
```

```
<?php

$first = $_POST["firstname"];
$last = $_POST["lastname"];

echo "first name = " . $first . "<br>";
echo "last name = " . $last;

?>
```

@aleation Unfortunately the server is on my work intranet. Here's a sample of data being posted from stage2 to stage3 using GET:

```
stage3.php?r1=729&save=Next&transcount=3&requesttype=invoice&requestedby=campbelld
```

Oddly, it's only sending those inputs which are set - stage2.php has a checkbox for each search result and it's only sent the one which was checked (row 1) so if I can't find a solution then using GET would be possible afterall. When I was testing at home it sent every checkbox so the URL ended up being massive.

Comment: I may be wrong, but you need to re-pass those variables through some sort of hidden input.

Comment: It would be nice if you paste some code of the 3 pages, it sounds weird anyway, and although I don't know if there's a limit on the query string actually, it should work or not work, shouldn't depend on the time. The only way I think it could depend on time is that between index.php and stage2.php you have some Sql query that is not optimized and takes a while to update the database. So as I said, please provide more details

Comment: I'm not trying to post the same variables. The 2nd form is completely different with it's own inputs. But the input values on the 2nd form won't post unless I wait for 10 secs.

Comment: @aleation see update above. There is a select query on stage2.php but I don't think that's the issue because I experience the same problem with the basic form above.

Comment: seems like page don't loads fully and inputs are empty when you try to submit form. i can guess that there are some js script or else for that inputs provided and they are slow enough?

Comment: Works well in my local machine... did you test the same script you pasted and still makes you wait 10 secs? If so: please paste an example of the variables your are passing (if possible) or link to your server/environment. Because it's quite strange, I don't think the problem might be in the script as it's quite simple. You might have something in your full script, or some issue with your server

Comment: If you are passing post values from one form to another, you need to include the previous post values in the second form. Typically that is done with hidden fields.